# Stop code execution when rejecting promise

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I have the following promise-returning function:

```
function createJourney() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // code ...
    doOperation((err, data) {
      // code ...
      return reject('We need to exit now!')
    });

    // ---> Why is code stil executing here? <---

  })
}
```

Why is the code executing below the reject? When rejecting, I want to stop the execution of the `createJourney` function.

I am using Bluebird promise.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  doThing1()
  doOperation(..);
  doThing2()
})
```

there is no reason why doThing2() should not be executed depending on what happens inside doOperation()

doOperation will probably start an asynchronous operation and doThing2 will be called long before reject is called in your example.